# Hierarchical query using Active Record

Tags: mysql, arrays, codeigniter, activerecord

I have records in my db table called **pages**

structure like:

```
id | parent_id | title
```

If **parent_id == 0** it means that the row is a parent

If **parent_id != 0** it means that the row is a child

I can get all the records using CodeIgniter activerecord like:

```
$query = $this->db->get('pages');
```

And the result is something like that:

```
Europe
Mexico
Spain
Africa
Germany
Canada
America
Egypt
France
```

But I need to reorder the result using some groupby or something so it groups all rows from db that have the same parent_id and after that make get(), so the result would be like:

```
Africa
    Egypt
America
    Canada
    Mexico
Europe
    Germany
    France
    Spain
```

**Where parent_id = 0 are Africa, America and Europe**

and

**Egypt has e.g. parent_id = 1
Canada and Mexico parent_id = 2
etc. according to the id of their parent**

How to do that?

Btw. the text indent and css is no problem, I am just curious about the result array for foreach loop itself.

Comment: Any idea hot to solve this problem?

Comment: i do not understand the structure of your table, is your parent and child on the same table?

Comment: With MySQL (lacking recursive queries) you can't do that purely with SQL. You need to do it in your client code or in a stored procedure

Comment: I can do it using 2 foreach loops (one within other) but I was thinking maybe it can be done using active record and do it it in my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do it:

```
select 
    c2.id, c1.title as continent, c2.name as country
from
    country as c1
        left outer join country as c2 ON (c1.id = c2.parent_id)
where
    c2.parent_id != 0
order by c1.title , c2.title
```

Given your sample data, this will produce:

```
8   Africa  Egypt
6   America Canada
2   America Mexico
9   Europe  France
5   Europe  Germany
3   Europe  Spain
```

UPDATE: 
If you want to mix the continents and countries in the same field use:

```
select 
    c2.id, c2.title as country
from
    country as c1
    left outer join
        country as c2 ON (c1.id = c2.parent_id or c1.id = c2.id and c2.parent_id = 0)
where
    c2.title is not null
order by 
    case 
        when c2.parent_id = 0 then c2.id else c2.parent_id end,
        c2.parent_id
```

This will give you the following output:

```
1   Europe
3   Spain
9   France
5   Germany
4   Africa
8   Egypt
7   America
6   Canada
2   Mexico
```

For use in codeigniter, the easiest way to do it is by not using the active record, just a simple query:

```
$sql = 'select 
    c2.id, c2.title as country
from
    country as c1
    left outer join
        country as c2 ON (c1.id = c2.parent_id or c1.id = c2.id and c2.parent_id = 0)
where
    c2.title is not null
order by 
    case 
        when c2.parent_id = 0 then c2.id else c2.parent_id end,
        c2.parent_id'

$result = $this->db->query($sql)->result();
```

Comment: Thanks but I need it included continents as a separate records too. This way they are missing. Order could be alphabetical as you have used, but it's not a concern right now. Important is that the parrents are included too. Could you also do it using CodeIgniter's active record?

Comment: Thanks, could you do it using CodeIgniter's  active record?

Comment: I do not think that case in the order by can be done in a nice way using the CI active record. I would run the query via $this->db->query($sql)->result() instead.

Comment: Could you explain or perhaps write in code if possibile? Thanks in advance.